# How to sort given list based on provided criteria in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to sort below list of object so that return list contains object in the order of provided key list. for example:

```
Given object list: 
my_list==> [{"ipnetworkaddress", [], "33.33.123.148"}, {"httpbrowsertype", [], "Mozilla"}, {"hostname", [], "example.com"}]

Given order list having object first attribute for criteria: 
ordered_keys ===> ["hostname", "httpbrowsertype", "ipnetworkaddress"]
    
Desired result ==> [{"hostname", [], "example.com"}, {"httpbrowsertype", [], "Mozilla"}, {"ipnetworkaddress", [], "33.33.123.148"} ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Enum.sort_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#sort_by/3) is your friend.

```rb
Enum.sort_by(my_list, &Enum.find_index(keys, fn e ->
  e == elem(&1, 0)
end), &<=/2)
#⇒ [
#   {"hostname", [], "example.com"},
#   {"httpbrowsertype", [], "Mozilla"},
#   {"ipnetworkaddress", [], "33.33.123.148"}
# ]
```

This is not the most performant solution, but the cleanest one, and for relatively short lists it’s good enough.

For each element in the list to be sorted, we find an index of its first element in the tuple and use this index for comparison in the ascending order.

Comment: The `&<=/2` could be omitted, because it's the default sorter of `Enum.sort_by/3`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just wanted to show the most generic approach (in a case they want to sort the list descending, for instance.)

Answer (score 3):

For short lists Aleksei's answer is fine, but for the specific case where you have a list of ordered keys, I would use [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) to group the objects by keys, and then [`Enum.flat_map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) over the ordered keys, looking up the relevant objects from the group. For larger lists, it means you're doing an O(log n) map lookup instead of an O(n) list search for each item.

```rb
objects = [
  {"ipnetworkaddress", [], "33.33.123.148"},
  {"httpbrowsertype", [], "Mozilla"},
  {"hostname", [], "example.com"}
]

ordered_keys = ["hostname", "httpbrowsertype", "ipnetworkaddress"]

grouped_objects = Enum.group_by(objects, &elem(&1, 0))

Enum.flat_map(ordered_keys, &grouped_objects[&1])
```